# Gvim doesn't start without sudo

Tags: bash, vim

I have just tried to open gvim but it doesn't start..It just shows the cursor blinking after running `$ gvim`.

I tried adding `sudo` before, and gvim is opened correctly.

After doing `ls -all /usr/bin/gv*` I get this line:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    22 Nov 28 10:31 /usr/bin/gvim -> /etc/alternatives/gvim
```

Any idea?

I don't have any problems to start vim without sudo.

**EDIT**: finally the problem was a hidden alias in .bashrc.. Please press "Close" to delete this question.

Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Try starting gvim with the -V flag to put it in verbose mode, i.e. `gvim -V`. This will spit out a whole load of info, and if it's freezing on something then you can spot it. It may not be a permission thing as much as it could be a problem that gvim has with something in your `.vimrc`; running as `sudo` would use a different `.vimrc`.

Comment: I agree with @JonathanCairns, it sounds like something is broken with your `.vimrc`. When you run vim with `sudo` it uses a different `.vimrc`. You could try running with the `gvim -u NONE` to run vim without your `.vimrc`.

Comment: you could also past the output of `strace gvim` in order to troubleshoot this more

Comment: @drizzt That is *not* a solution.